# Unexplained space below span

Tags: css

I would need to get rid of the space below the two `span` tags and don't understand what causes them to be there.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <span></span><span></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
}
span {
  width: 13px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}
span:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

https://jsfiddle.net/wjy5hxnu/

Comment: I don't seem to see a space between the two span ?

Comment: The unwanted space is below the two `span` tags.

Comment: font-size:0 is a hack, use alignment like detailed in the duplicate

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you! Adding `vertical-align: middle` to the `span` worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the updated jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a2hb6wr4/).

```
div {
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

Adding `font-size: 0` to `div` will solve the problem and if you have to use any text inside span you can add font-size directly in the span.

Answer (score -1):

```
div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 11px;
}
```

Line height will lower the div to meet the line.